# Extra empty row generating while displaying data through php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I don't know why this code generates an extra row in the last, it only happens when i use PHP to display my data. There's no extra row in table tho. The extra row shows empty data.

```
 <div class="tbl-header">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $data = mysqli_query($con, "select `shopifyv2`.`products`.`ID` AS `ID`,`shopifyv2`.`products`.`ProductName` AS `ProductName`,`shopifyv2`.`brands`.`BrandName` AS `BrandName`,`shopifyv2`.`category`.`Name` AS `CategoryName`,`shopifyv2`.`products`.`Description` AS `Description`,`shopifyv2`.`products`.`Picture` AS `Picture`,`shopifyv2`.`products`.`Quantity` AS `Quantity`,`shopifyv2`.`products`.`Price` AS `Price` from `products` join `shopifyv2`.`brands` on `products`.`BrandID` = `brands`.`ID` join `shopifyv2`.`category` on `products`.`CateID` = `category`.`ID`");
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($data);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td><td>$row[4]</td><td><img height='30' width='20' src='../AdminPanel/Pictures/$row[5]'/ /></td><td>$row[6]</td><td>$row[7]</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='ModifyProduct.php?ID=$row[0]' class='btn btn-info'>Modify</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='ShowProduct.php?id=$row[0]'>Delete</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                $delid = $_GET['id'];
                mysqli_query($con, "delete from products where id = $delid");
                header("location: ShowProduct.php");
            }
        ?>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: whats the out put for `$row[0]`

Comment: It displays ID.

Comment: no try to check your called data from the database one bye one you will find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check if the row is not empty:

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($data);

for ($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
   if(!$row[0]) continue; // <- HERE
```